# Is it ever possible for command redirection to HDD to fail?

Tags: ubuntu, io-redirection, latex

I'm using Xubuntu 15.04, and sometimes have this really strange problem, originating from a `XeLaTeX` run. When using this typesetting system, the following system command is executed:

```
uname -s > <docname>.w18
```

where `<docname>` is the document name being compiled. After executing this command, from time to time `XeLaTeX` halts as being unable to locate such file, and the problem persists until I log out and back in or reboot the computer.

I've already discarded problems with `uname -s`, as it just prints `Linux` to the terminal when executed alone.

*Should I have to check my HDD? Can redirection ever fail?*

**P.S.** I'll add more information as needed.

***Edit.*** [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268486/xelatex-and-ifplatform-catchfile-loaded-by-minted-errors-on-compilation) you can find the question more `LaTeX` oriented, if needed.

***Edit 2.*** I attach the result of the suggested command here. It normally generates a lot of logs, but in this cases it only generated one.

```
$ strace -o lotsalogs -ff -e trace=file xelatex --shell-escape proba.tex
```

Output: [Here](http://pastebin.com/m2xSW7xU)

***Edit 3:*** [Here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bzo-YAkyyi6ea3JNZlBLNUlva3c&usp=sharing) you can find the output of the same command in normal circumstances.

Comment: What is the error message when `uname -s >file` in unsuccessful?

Comment: @chaos As it's executed internally by `XeLaTeX`, seeing the logs it generates doesn't provide such information. It only executes it, and then halts because it couldn't find the supposedly generated file.

Comment: I'll check the command alone as soon as it fails again.

Comment: I added a suggestion for the /latex tag, in which is a link to http://tex.stackexchange.com/, where someone may have more experience with this situation.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've asked there, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268486/xelatex-and-ifplatform-catchfile-loaded-by-minted-errors-on-compilation) is the link to the question if needed. It describes the problem in the `LaTeX` side.

Comment: `df` or `df -i` would show if you're running out of space (or inodes) which may cause the inability to write to a file (or also disk quotas, if those are in effect). Otherwise, perhaps `strace -o lotsalogs -ff -e trace=file` the mess and grep for that filename?

Comment: @thrig Nope, I have just checked `df` and at most I'm using 51% of one of my disks, with at most 16% of inodes used. As for the `strace` command, do I have to write it as you did?

Comment: `strace -o lotsalogs -ff -e trace=file xelatex --shell-escape`

Comment: @thrig Thanks! I've run it and generates a bunch of files [that's why the `lotsalogs` ;) ]. I will repeat this procedure when it fails, as right now it's just compiling fine. This issue happens without notice or apparent cause.

Comment: I have added the log when the command fails. @thrig

Answer (score 0):

`strace` shows lots of `*.sty` searches in presumably a directory list, then

```
# unusual, but eventually reads /dev/null, so might be normal?
access("./nul:.tex", R_OK)              = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("./nul:", R_OK)                  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Right after that there's a search for `proba.w18` or `proba.w18.tex` in the usual list of directories, though there's no system call for anything opening or writing to the file, prior, so given this `strace` I'd have to guess something got set to `/dev/null` somehow, and the desired information written there? Or that bit could be a false lead. Are there any `strace` differences on a good run?

Comment: The `sty` files are custom packages I've made, and they're stored where the log states. Let me run the command again when it doesn't fail, and then edit the question with the results.

Comment: And about the logs when running in good conditions, the most obvious difference is that `strace` generates a lot of log files. Let me put them on cloud for you to analyse them.

Comment: @logo_writer hmm, new logs are also showing `./nul:.tex` like the failed run did, so that's (probably) normal. I'd guess this is something in the latex, as there's nothing obviously awry in the failed strace.